# What does System.Concurrency.AsyncLock do?

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, locking, system.reactive

The System.Reactive.dll adds a class AsyncLock to System.Concurrency.
It has a single instance method, Wait, that takes an Action.

The [documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.concurrency.asynclock.wait%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) I found just tells it it pre-release documentation,
so I ask here: What does this class do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some sort of thread-safe queue that executes actions in sequential order. I see it's used in RX's schedulers.

You might wish to confirm with the RX team.

Comment: Nowadays the source is available, so I was finally able to confirm that you were right, based on comments and code here: https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Concurrency/AsyncLock.cs

Comment: Thanks for confirming this, even if it was 9 years later! :-)